# Error al importar archivo CSV a una tabla en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

estoy desarrollando un aplicativo y necesito hacer un import a mi tabla usuarios.
Estoy utilizando este codigo:

```html
<?php
include 'db.php';

 if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
   

   echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {

      $file = fopen($filename, "r");
           while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
           {
      
            //Inserto los datos del CSV a la tabla
             $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_tipousuario, responsable, telefono, documento, username, passwd) 
             VALUES('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]')";

           
      $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
     mysql_set_charset('utf8');
     if(! $result )
     {
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert(\"Invalid File:Por favor suba un archivo CSV.\");
        window.location = \"importar_usuarios.php\"
       </script>";
     
     }

           }
           fclose($file);
           //Mensaje si todo se importo correctamente
           echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
       alert(\"CSV ha sido correctamente importado.\");
       window.location = \"importar_usuarios.php\"
      </script>";
          
     

     //cierra la conex
    mysql_close($conn); 
     
     
    
    }
  }

?>
```

Tengo 2 dudas principales:

1. En mi tabla usuarios el primer campo es un ID auto incrementable automaticamente, deberia de incluir ese campo al momento de subirlo en el archivo CSV?
2. He probado subirlo incluyendo el campo 0 (el ID que mencionaba) y sin incluirlo, de ambas formas me devuelve el mensaje de que por favor suba un archivo CSV.
   Quite el JS para ver exactamente cuales eran los errores y esto es lo que me devuelve: 
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria mucho me ayudaran, de antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de varias pruebas descubri que solo tenia que quitar el '$emapData[6]', cosa que me parece raro porque ya antes habia probado sin el, pero bueno, logre solucionarlo.